# Is React Native compatible with PhpStorm?

Tags: javascript, react-native, phpstorm

I recently switched from VSC to PhpStorm. I was wondering about React Native compatibility in PhpStorm. Especially code completion does not work at all.

VSC (with React plugin):
[image: https://imgur.com/299EW5C]

PhpStorm:
[image: https://imgur.com/YSU1O6n]

I expected full compatibility since it's mentioned in the documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/react-native.html

Any plugin I need to install or why is it not working?

Comment: could you share code snippets that show how your component is defined and imported? Can be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-45245

Comment: Here are some snippets (no way of formatting it correctly in a comment, sorry):

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const MyScreen = React.memo(({navigation, route}) => {
...

  return (
    <View style={MainStyles.screen}>
      <FlatList
        data={data.data}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem={renderData}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Check that the Javascript and TypeScript & JavaScript Debugger extensions are enabled. If the plugins are enabled but Intellisense doesn't work, check that your files has the .jsx or the .tsx extension.